# Open a bunch of JSON files and change value of a key

Tags: json, file, automation

I have over 500 JSON files where I have to change a value of a **lang** key from **en** to **de**

This is how the structure of the files looks like

```
{
  "id": "a7b9e1b4-3d91-4e1b-946a-8c4b92b78d31",
  "name": "smart.emoji.gb.country",
  "auto": true,
  "contexts": [],
  "responses": [
    {
      "resetContexts": false,
      "affectedContexts": [],
      "parameters": [],
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "lang": "en",
          "speech": "Country Flag"
        }
      ],
      "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
      "speech": []
    }
  ],
  "priority": 500000,
  "webhookUsed": false,
  "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
  "lastUpdate": 1525736163,
  "fallbackIntent": false,
  "events": []
}
```

All the files are in the same folder.

Any idea how can I do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer - Notepad++ has this functionality.